# Why is plasma glucose concentration not double that of whole blood?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques, medicine, medicinal-chemistry, blood-sugar

It is known that the concentration of plasma glucose is [12% higher than](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/1122647/) that of whole blood. But since 45-50% of whole blood is red blood cells, shouldn't the plasma glucose be almost double — since it's just the hematocrit that is missing from the denominator.

Obviously something is wrong with this line of reasoning, since it does not meet the observations. Why so? Does whole blood glucose also measure intra-cellular glucose? Is that the reason for the lesser than expected increase?

Comment: What units are you talking about — concentration or amount? Please cite values with units, then we can address your question. Otherwise it is unclear and I, for one, will vote to close it on these grounds.

Comment: @David I've edited the question, I'm talking about the glucose concentrations in whichever units.

Comment: Quoting from the paper: "Within one hour after blood collection protein-free filtrates were prepared from whole blood and plasma according to Somogyi [6] in the following modification [7] : to 2.0 ml of distilled water 0.4 ml of whole blood was added and mixed. Then 0.8 ml each of balanced zinc suiphate and barium hydroxide solutions were added, in this order, slowly and with constant mixing. The mixtures were then centrifuged for 10 minutes at 3000 rpm. (2000 X g). The protein-free filtrates were carefully sucked off with Pasteur pipettes." i.e. the measurements include intracellular glucose.